# runtime detection whether ARMv7 ELF binaries can be loaded on ARMv6 host

Tags: linux, arm, armv7, binary-compatibility, armv6

Consider a host application that has been compiled for `armv6` (think: Raspbian) and can `dlopen()` extensions/plugins.
Some of these plugins might be compiled for `armv7`.

If the host application is running on a recent hardware, there shouldn't be any problem loading and running these plugins.
OTOH, if the application is running on legacy hardware (e.g. RPi2), the `dlopen()` will probably fail.

Now I would like to determine, whether the host application is capable of loading `armv7` binaries, without actually trying to do so.

My use case is: writing a package manager that queries an online resource for available plugins; only compatible packages should be displayed: if the host is running on armv6, only armv6 plugins will be shown, but if it is running on armv7 both armv7 and armv6 binaries are presented.

The package architecture (as can be queried via the online resource) is detected via something like `readelf -A <binary> | grep Tag_CPU_arch`.

My original attempt used the `__ARM_ARCH` macro on the host, but that is obviously a compile-time check rather than a runtime check.
On x86, there's `__builtin_cpu_supports()` (for gcc and friends), but that is not available on ARM.
Parsing `/proc/cpuinfo` might be an option, but honestly I have no clue what to check for...

Ideas?

Comment: like `uname -m` ? https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/uname.c#L318 . Like lscpu : https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/441f9b9303d015f1777aec7168807d58feacca31/sys-utils/lscpu-cputype.c#L586

Comment: maybe; is there a way to get the output of `uname` via some library calls? (rather than `execv("uname")` ?

Comment: also, `uname -m` feels somewhat wrong: e.g. on x86, I could run an `i386` binary on an `arm64` host, and the `i386`-host definitely won't be able to dlopen() an `arm64`-plugin. (although this is probably true for all the solutions)

Comment: `Parsing /proc/cpuinfo might be an option` I would go with parsing it. https://gist.github.com/frbayart/62a779aadee72ed2cc2f -> you could check for vfpv4 for example.

Comment: it turns out that there's [`uname(2)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) which might be just what i was looking for.